# Building large chemical models such as VANTAblack

Tags: graphics3d, chemistry

I would like to build a (large) molecular model of the nanotubes that make up [VANTAblack](https://vantablack172.wordpress.com/environmental-impact/), which consists of a sheet of hexagonally connected carbon atoms all rolled into a (teeny) tube.

I can easily do this with `Graphics3D` using `Spheres` and `Tube` segments.  However, I would like to retain the graphics style used in other `MoleculePlots`.

There seem to be two approaches:

1. Create the model and render it in `Graphics3D` and try to mimic, by hand, the style of `MoleculePlots`.  I'm not eager to do that, because the styles never quite match.  (Might there be some compiled "chemical structure" graphics style?)
2. Somehow create the (large) molecular structure and use `MoleculePlot` to render it.

Any suggestions on how to best proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer uses the [web-based front end](http://turin.nss.udel.edu/research/tubegenonline.html) for [TubeGen](http://turin.nss.udel.edu/sw/tubegen) to generate an XYZ file, and then `Import` it.

I think it would be a fun project to write a more direct link to the program, source code [here](https://gitlab.com/jtfrey/tubegen), but this works in a pinch.

Be aware this is hitting a free web-based service, and don't overload it.

```
template = StringTemplate @ "https://turin.nss.udel.edu/cgi-bin/tubegen-online?n-value=`n`&m-value=`m`&element-1=C&element-2=C&bond=1.4210&shape=`shape`&x-gutter=1.6735&y-gutter=1.6735&z-gutter=0.0000&x-count=`x`&y-count=`y`&z-count=`z`&format=xyz&units=angstrom&relax_tube=on";
default = <|
    "x" -> 1, "z" -> 10, "y" -> 1, "shape" -> "hexagonal", "n" -> 3, "m" -> 3
|>;
nanotube[params_Association : <||>, return_String : "Graphics3D"] := Module[
    {url = template @ Join[default, params]},
    Import[url, {"XYZ", return}]
];
```

For the usage we have

```
nanotube[]
```

[image]

or

```
nanotube[<|"n" -> 6, "m" -> 6|>]
```

[image]

or

```
nanotube[<|"z" -> 13, "shape" -> "planar"|>]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this is *so* very helpful.  Thanks.  (of course +1).  But the only additional step I need is to get the style like my other styles, as illustrated:  `ChemicalData["Caffeine", "MoleculePlot"]`. Is there any way to impose that style?  After all, this is really a wonderful way to create the model, but not the *style*, which is my central issue.

Comment: Oh... wait... it seems that because there are only carbon atoms, everything is black.  So yes... you solved it.  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: It should have the same styling as that, it calls the system `MoleculePlot3D` function, but all the atoms are carbon and so they are all slate gray.  So you could call `SetOptions[MoleculePlot3D, ColorRules -> {"C" -> Purple}]` before running this and the atoms are all purple.  The web interface has an option for using non-carbon atoms, but I haven't played around with it yet.  I think you'd modify the string template where it says `"element-1=C&element-2=C"` and put alternate atoms there.